# Wordpress, save_post, post_status isnt the excatly what in the database

Tags: wordpress

```
add_action("save_post", [$this, "save"]);

function save($postId)
{
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    echo $post->post_status; // its "inherit" instead of "publish" !
    echo $post->post_status; // its "revision" instead of "draft" !
}
```

and then in database there is "`publish`", I get `get_post($post_id)->post_status` => '`inherit`' !

or in database there is "`draft`", I get `get_post($post_id)->post_status` => '`revision`' !

Why? I need to do some operations based on post_status and I cant do it like that

Comment: you should look into this hook instead maybe : https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Comment: then you can target the post statuses and transitions, and do whatever you want, when you want

Comment: I am curious If you use the second parameter of the action 'save_post' which is the post object what is the post_status?

Comment: I have read the source code and using get_post() retrieves an object from the cache and using the second parameter should give you the object that was saved. I wonder if they could be different.